# Reset functions without having to refresh the page

Tags: javascript, html, input, calculator

So i'm fooling around with some math functions, and i met a problem. I have a few inputs with "onClick", but my problem is: 
I can do the calcutations once, but if I try again, it wont work. I then have to refresh the page before I can try with new values. Anyone knows how to fix this?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Quadratic equation Calculator</h1>
</br>
</br>
<p>Select A value</p> <input id="a"></input>
<p>Select B value</p> <input id="b"></input>
<p>Select C value</p> <input id="c"></input></br>
<button class="knapp" onClick="a();b();c();abc(a,b,c)">Calculate</button>
<button class="knapp" onClick="location.href=location.href">Refresh</button>

<h1 id="svar"></h1>
<h1 id="svar2"></h1>
   

<script>
 
 function a() {
  a = document.getElementById("a").value;
  return a;
 }
 function b() {
  b = document.getElementById("b").value;
  return b;
 }
 function c() {
  c = document.getElementById("c").value;
  return c;
 }
 
 
 
 
 function abc(a,b,c) {
 
  var minB = -b;
  var underRot = Math.pow(b,2)-(4*a*c);
  var rot = Math.sqrt(underRot);
  var formelPluss = (minB + rot)/(2*a);
  var formelMinus = (minB - rot)/(2*a);
  
  document.getElementById("svar").innerHTML = "X1 = " + formelPluss;
  document.getElementById("svar2").innerHTML = "X2 = " + formelMinus;
  
 }
 
</script>





</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of the functions `a`, `b` and `c` you are re-defining itself because you are using the same name as the function in the input value variable, so you just have to change its name like this:

```
var valueOfA, valueOfB, valueOfC;
function a() {
    valueOfA = document.getElementById("a").value;
    return valueOfA;
}
function b() {
    valueOfB = document.getElementById("b").value;
    return valueOfB;
}
function c() {
    valueOfC = document.getElementById("c").value;
    return valueOfC;
}
```

Then use your newly created variables in the calculate function instead of the old ones:

```
<button class="knapp" onClick="a();b();c(); abc(valueOfA, valueOfB, valueOfC)">Calculate</button>
```

Also, if you are using `a`, `b`, and `c` just to return a value you can make it with a simplified like so:

```
function getInputValue(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id).value;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
<button class="knapp" onClick="abc(getInputValue('a'), getInputValue('b'), getInputValue('c'));">Calculate</button>
```

The full snippet would be:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Quadratic equation Calculator</h1>
</br>
</br>
<p>Select A value</p> <input id="a" />
<p>Select B value</p> <input id="b" />
<p>Select C value</p> <input id="c" /><br />
<button class="knapp" onClick="abc(getInputValue('a'), getInputValue('b'), getInputValue('c'))">Calculate</button>
<button class="knapp" onClick="location.href=location.href">Refresh</button>

<h1 id="svar"></h1>
<h1 id="svar2"></h1>
   

<script>
    function getInputValue(id) {
        return document.getElementById(id).value;
    }
 
    function abc(a, b, c) {
        //console.log(a, b, c);
 
        var minB = -b;
        var underRot = Math.pow(b,2)-(4*a*c);
        var rot = Math.sqrt(underRot);
        var formelPluss = (minB + rot)/(2*a);
        var formelMinus = (minB - rot)/(2*a);
  
        document.getElementById("svar").innerHTML = "X1 = " + formelPluss;
        document.getElementById("svar2").innerHTML = "X2 = " + formelMinus;
  
    }
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks! This really helped me out!

Comment: Of course, if you think this is the answer you were looking for, could you please mark it? @Benjamhw

Answer (score 1):

You need to set them as variables using `let`.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Quadratic equation Calculator</h1>
</br>
</br>
<p>Select A value</p> <input id="a"></input>
<p>Select B value</p> <input id="b"></input>
<p>Select C value</p> <input id="c"></input></br>
<button class="knapp" onClick="a();b();c();abc(a,b,c)">Calculate</button>
<button class="knapp" onClick="location.href=location.href">Refresh</button>

<h1 id="svar"></h1>
<h1 id="svar2"></h1>
   

<script>
 
 function a() {
  let a = document.getElementById("a").value;
  return a;
 }
 function b() {
  let b = document.getElementById("b").value;
  return b;
 }
 function c() {
  let c = document.getElementById("c").value;
  return c;
 }
 
 
 
 
 function abc(a,b,c) {
 
  var minB = -b;
  var underRot = Math.pow(b,2)-(4*a*c);
  var rot = Math.sqrt(underRot);
  var formelPluss = (minB + rot)/(2*a);
  var formelMinus = (minB - rot)/(2*a);
  
  document.getElementById("svar").innerHTML = "X1 = " + formelPluss;
  document.getElementById("svar2").innerHTML = "X2 = " + formelMinus;
  
 }
 
</script>





</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but now a,b and c cannot be used in the function? I just get NaN on whatever i try to console.log. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach :

```js
 function abc(a,b,c) {
 a = document.getElementById("a").value;
   b = document.getElementById("b").value;
    c = document.getElementById("c").value;
  var minB = -b;
  var underRot = Math.pow(b,2)-(4*a*c);
  var rot = Math.sqrt(underRot);
  var formelPluss = (minB + rot)/(2*a);
  var formelMinus = (minB - rot)/(2*a);
  
  document.getElementById("svar").innerHTML = "X1 = " + formelPluss;
  document.getElementById("svar2").innerHTML = "X2 = " + formelMinus;
  
 }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Quadratic equation Calculator</h1>
</br>
</br>
<p>Select A value</p> <input id="a"></input>
<p>Select B value</p> <input id="b"></input>
<p>Select C value</p> <input id="c"></input></br>
<button class="knapp" onClick="abc(a,b,c)">Calculate</button>
   

<h1 id="svar"></h1>
<h1 id="svar2"></h1>






</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some unnecessary calls. I've edited your code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Quadratic equation Calculator</h1>
</br>
</br>
<p>Select A value</p> <input id="a"></input>
<p>Select B value</p> <input id="b"></input>
<p>Select C value</p> <input id="c"></input></br>
<button class="knapp" onClick="abc()">Calculate</button>
<button class="knapp" onClick="location.href=location.href">Refresh</button>

<h1 id="svar"></h1>
<h1 id="svar2"></h1>


<script>


    function abc() {
        var a = document.getElementById("a").value;
        var b = document.getElementById("b").value;
        var c = document.getElementById("c").value;
        var minB = -b;
        var underRot = Math.pow(b,2)-(4*a*c);
        var rot = Math.sqrt(underRot);
        var formelPluss = (minB + rot)/(2*a);
        var formelMinus = (minB - rot)/(2*a);

        document.getElementById("svar").innerHTML = "X1 = " + formelPluss;
        document.getElementById("svar2").innerHTML = "X2 = " + formelMinus;

    }

</script>





</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your code is, you declared functions as "a","b" and "c" and also storing the return value in the same variable. Either rename the variables or functions name. It will solve the problem. or you can define the scope of the variable using let keyword.

here is modified code:

```
function a1() {
     a = document.getElementById("a").value;
    return a;
}
function b1() {
     b = document.getElementById("b").value;
    return b;
}
function c1() {
     c = document.getElementById("c").value;
    return c;
}
```